# I am not able to append list using loops in scala

Tags: arrays, list, scala, for-loop, collections

```
object LoopList extends App {
  var even_list = List()
  var odd_list = List()

  for (i <- Range(1,10)) {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
      even_list = even_list :+ i
    } else {
      odd_list = odd_list :+ i
    }
  }

  println(even_list)
}
```

I am trying to create 2 simple lists for odd and even, although i know lists are immutable but i tried tuples as well. Please suggest a way to new solution using for loop only.

Comment: All you need to do is fix the way you instantiate both `Lists`: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Lyg05tTrSGOkrDagIgKpjg/1 - Anyways, all this code can be simplified as `val (evens, odds) = List.range(0, 10).partition(i => (i % 2) == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell the problem is that at the point of their declaration the compiler doesn't have enough information to determine the type of the items in the list. As such, it determines that the list is a `List[Nothing]` and the compiler tells you that you are trying to add an `Int` but that it needs `Nothing`.

To solve the problem, you can add a simple type annotation as in the following example:

```
var even_list: List[Int] = List()
var odd_list: List[Int] = List()

for (i <- Range(1, 10)) {
  if ((i % 2) == 0) {
    even_list = even_list :+ i
  } else {
    odd_list = odd_list :+ i
  }
}

println(even_list)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/bsOYmCN6TbKMXF88jJTfAQ/1).

As suggested in a comment, you are definitely encouraged to experiment with the Collection API of the Scala standard library, which provides you with very powerful constructs to create your programs in a way that is compact and readable, as in the example provided above to construct the lists with a single line of code:

```
val (evens, odds) = List.range(1, 10).partition(i => (i % 2) == 0)
```

Comment: Is usually preferred to call the `empty` factory rather than an empty `apply`

Comment: `Nil` is a canonical empty `List`.

Comment: Yeah i missed giving the type to the list. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Also single line of code is amazing too. from now on i will try to experiment more and more for basic things.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, appending an element is an extremely slow `List` operation. If it possible, it is better to use reverse order to construct a `List`:

```
    var even_list: List[Int] = Nil
    var odd_list: List[Int] = Nil

    for (i <- 9 to 1 by -1) {
      if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        even_list = i :: even_list
      } else {
        odd_list = i :: odd_list
      }
    }

    println(even_list)
    println(odd_list)
```

Or use another suitable collection with following conversion to a `List`.

Comment: Very good point, thanks for mentioning that!